# How can I get the content of CKEditor using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor. I am saving the form values with ajax using page methods.

But the content of CKEditor value cannot be saving into the table.

I dont postback the page.

What can I do for that?

Answer (score -21, accepted):

First of all you should include ckeditor and jquery connector script in your page,

then create a textarea

```
<textarea name="content" class="editor" id="ms_editor"></textarea>
```

attach ckeditor to the text area, in my project I use something like this:

```
$('textarea.editor').ckeditor(function() {
        }, { toolbar : [
            ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Print', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt'],
            ['Undo','Redo'],
            ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','-','Subscript','Superscript'],
            ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','Blockquote'],
            ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
            ['Link','Unlink','Anchor', 'Image', 'Smiley'],
            ['Table','HorizontalRule','SpecialChar'],
            ['Styles','BGColor']
        ], toolbarCanCollapse:false, height: '300px', scayt_sLang: 'pt_PT', uiColor : '#EBEBEB' } );
```

on submit get the content using:

```
var content = $( 'textarea.editor' ).val();
```

That's it! :)

Comment: Thanks for answer but i dont postback the page and thats why i cannot get the content of ckeditor. My issue is how can i get the content of ckeditor without postback using jquery.

Comment: The answer below is much better.

Comment: It's the first time I've seen such a negatively-voted answer as the accepted one. Incredible.

Comment: Poor guy ... So much words, -19.

Answer (score 208):

use the [CKEditor.editor.getData()](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#getData) call on the instance. That is to say:

HTML

```html
<textarea id="my-editor">
<input id="send" type="button" value="Send">
```

---

JS for CKEditor 4.0.x

```js
$('#send').click(function() {
    var value = CKEDITOR.instances['DOM-ID-HERE'].getData()
    // send your ajax request with value
    // profit!
});
```

JS for CKEditor 3.6.x

```js
var editor = CKEDITOR.editor.replace('my-editor');

$('#send').click(function() {
    var value = editor.getData();
    // send your ajax request with value
    // profit!
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working with the latest version of CKEditor (4.0.2 - 6 Mar 2013). The answer below does however: `CKEDITOR.instances['DOM-ID-HERE'].getData();`

Comment: It's actually much easier than that. Just do `$('.my-editor-class').val()` See my answer bellow.

Answer (score 71):

If you don't hold a reference to the editor, as in Aeon's answer, you can also use the form:

```
var value = CKEDITOR.instances['my-editor'].getData();
```

If you do not save your data with a library that already encodes it by using the JavaScript encodeURIComponent method, but do it manually instead, you will have to remember to use encodeURIComponent to properly encode the data that is being sent.

So you should do below:

```
var value = encodeURIComponent(CKEDITOR.instances['my-editor'].getData());
```

For more info: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_savedata.html

Comment: +1 to you sir. Spent ages looking for how to get the data from 1 instance of CKEDITOR (where there are X instances initialised via the class "editor"). Ended up with: `var strData = CKEDITOR.instances['editor_'+intCounter].getData();` - in case it's useful to anybody else.

Answer (score 9):

```
var value = CKEDITOR.instances['YourInstanceName'].getData()
 alert( value);
```

Replace `YourInstanceName` with the name of your instance and you will get the desired results.

Answer (score 7):

I was having issues with the `getData()` not working every time especially when dealing with live ajax.

Was able to get around it by running:

```
for(var instanceName in CKEDITOR.instances){
    CKEDITOR.instances[instanceName].updateElement();
}
```

Then use jquery to get the value from the textarea.

Answer (score 5):

Now that [jQuery adapter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR_Adapters.jQuery) exists, this answer needs to be updated:

Say you initiated the editor with `$('.ckeditor').ckeditor(opt)` then you get the value with `$('.ckeditor').val()`

Comment: At the time the question was asked, I do not think the jQuery adapter existed. Thank you for the answer though, it's definitely a valid way to do it too these days.

Comment: This doesn't do a thing for me. Empty string result.

Comment: OK, it doesnt work with an ID, it does work with the initial selector :)

Answer (score 3):

To get data of ckeditor, you need to get ckeditor instance

HTML code:

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="reply_mail_msg" name="message" rows="3" data-form-field="Message" placeholder="" autofocus="" style="display: none;"></textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
var ck_ed = CKEDITOR.instances.reply_mail_msg.getData();
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to John Magnolia. This is my postForm function that I am using in my Symfony projects and it is fine now to work with CK Editor.

```
function postForm($form, callback)
{
  // Get all form values
  var values = {};
  var fields = {};

  for(var instanceName in CKEDITOR.instances){
      CKEDITOR.instances[instanceName].updateElement();
  }

  $.each($form.serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
      values[field.name] = field.value;
  });

  // Throw the form values to the server!
  $.ajax({
      type        : $form.attr('method'),
      url         : $form.attr('action'),
      data        : values,
      success     : function(data) {
          callback( data );
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can retreive data like this :

```
<script>
var data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
// Your code to save "data", usually through Ajax.
</script>
```

reference :
http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_savedata

Answer (score 1):

version 4.8.0

```
$('textarea').data('ckeditorInstance').getData();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Pure Vanilla Javascript / Jquery or in any javascript library :

If you have Ckeditor loaded in below text-area:

```
 <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1"></textarea>
```

Then you can get content inside textarea as below:

```
var txtNotes = document.getElementsByClassName('ck-content')[0].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

i add ckEditor by adding DLL in toolBox.

 html code:

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="editor1" runat="server" 
            BasePath="ckeditor" ContentsCss="ckeditor/contents.css" 
            Height="250px" 
            TemplatesFiles="ckeditor/themes/default/theme.js" FilebrowserBrowseUrl="ckeditor/plugins/FileManager/index.html" 
            FilebrowserFlashBrowseUrl="ckeditor/plugins/FileManager/index.html" FilebrowserFlashUploadUrl="ckeditor/plugins/FileManager/index.html" 
            FilebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl="ckeditor/plugins/FileManager/index.html" FilebrowserImageBrowseUrl="ckeditor/plugins/FileManager/index.html" 
            FilebrowserImageUploadUrl="ckeditor/plugins/FileManager/index.html" 
            FilebrowserUploadUrl="ckeditor/plugins/FileManager/index.html" BackColor="#FF0066" 
                    DialogButtonsOrder="Rtl" 
                    FontNames="B Yekan;B Yekan,tahoma;Arial/Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; Comic Sans MS/Comic Sans MS, cursive; Courier New/Courier New, Courier, monospace; Georgia/Georgia, serif; Lucida Sans Unicode/Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif; Tahoma/Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; Times New Roman/Times New Roman, Times, serif; Trebuchet MS/Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif; Verdana/Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif" 
                    ResizeDir="Vertical" ResizeMinHeight="350" UIColor="#CACACA">dhd fdh</CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

for get data of it.

jquery:

```
var editor  = $('textarea iframe html body').html();
    alert(editor);
```

Comment: hi,for me return back 'undefined'.i added by dll file.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be better, just serialize your form by jquery and cheers...

```html
<form id="ajxForm">
  <!-- input elments here -->
  <textarea id="ck-editor" name="ck-editor" required></textarea>
  <input name="text" id="text" type="text" required> 
<form>
```

and In javascript section

```js
CKEDITOR.replace('ck-editor', {
  extraPlugins: 'sourcedialog',
  removePlugins: 'sourcearea'
});

$("form#ajxForm").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = $(this).serialize();
  if (data != '') {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'post.php',
      cache: false,
      type: 'POST',
      data: data,
      success: function(e) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          alert(e);
        }, 6500);
      }
    });
  }
  return;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

version `4.6`

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData()
```

Comment: while the answer may be accurate, it is hard to understand why this is the answer. Please add a brief explanation for the benefit of the community

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [answer]. You should provide some information why your code solves the problem.
Code-only answers aren't useful for the community.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to get the text inside of the editor or the length of it :)

```
 var editorText = CKEDITOR.instances['<%= your_editor.ClientID %>'].getData();
 alert(editorText);

 var editorTextLength = CKEDITOR.instances['<%= your_editor.ClientID %>'].getData().length;
 alert(editorTextLength);
```