# Unable to get content from CKEditor properly

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I used the solution available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8565966/586051) to fetch content of CKEditor. However it is fetching the content enclosed in `<p>` tag. How do I get rid of the `<p>` tag?

**Update**: The solution given in the [documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery) is not working either.

Comment: Yes, I would like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could get raw content by doing:

```
var html=CKEDITOR.instances.your_element_id.getSnapshot();
var divEle=document.createElement("DIV");
divEle.innerHTML=html;
var plain_text=(divEle.textContent || divEle.innerText);
console.log(plain_text); //heres your raw content
```

**Update::**

Updated Demo [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7b3j2/1/)

Comment: Its throwing an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getSnapshot' of undefined `

Comment: @RahulDesai is your ckeditor loaded..? and where are you adding the code, try adding it just before closing of body tag..

Comment: CKEditor is loaded. And yes, I am adding the code just before closing body tag. I tried to create a fiddle but it is not working: http://jsfiddle.net/7b3j2/

Comment: @RahulDesai see updated demo jsfiddle, its working fine.. :: http://jsfiddle.net/7b3j2/1/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What was I missing?