# How to get content from ckeditor using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor control in asp.net as shown below.

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" BasePath="/ckeditor/" runat="server">
```

How to get the content from the above editor using jquery?

Comment: See this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799317/how-can-i-get-content-of-ckeditor-using-jquery

Comment: It all depends on how it is rendered. So of you can give us rendered html then we can provide solution.

Comment: See this http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/317_Using_CKEditor_3x_[aka_FCKeditor]_with_jQuery_in_ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#CKEditor1').ckeditor(function() {
            var editor = $('#TextBox1').ckeditorGet();
        //Your code goes here
         }, { toolbar: 'Basic'});

            $('#CKEditor1').val("<b>I love CKEditor!!</b>");
            alert("jquery way" + $('#CKEditor1').val());

        });

    </script>
```

You can refer more at http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/317_Using_CKEditor_3x_[aka_FCKeditor]_with_jQuery_in_ASPNet.aspx