# Get value of Textarea doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, ckeditor

This is my html code:

```
<textarea class="form-control ckeditor" name="home_b1" id="home_b1">
  <article style="width: 55%;">
    <h2 style="text-align:center">
      <span style="color:#82b04e;font-size:24px">
        Experience the power of going prepaid
      </span>
    </h2>
    <h4 style="text-align:center">
      <span style="color:#82b04e;font-size:15px">
        Pick the plan you want with the carrier you want.
      </span>
    </h4>
    <br>
    <p style="margin-left:60px;text-align:justify;">
      <span style="font-size:20px">
        Some Text
      </span>
    </p>
  </article>
</textarea>
```

And here is my jquery code:

```
$('#btnPreview').on('click',function(){
  var block1 = $('#home_b1').html();
  alert(block1);
});
```

When I write on the texteare, and i click on the bottom, it doesn't show me the current content, it shows the DOM content.

Comment: i tried with .val(); and it doesn't work also.

Comment: `javascript` at Question appears to return expected result, here

Comment: I don't think that markup is valid. What is it that you expect that markup in the `<textarea>` to do? The browser will show it as raw HTML content.

Comment: Are you using CKEditor, right?

Comment: There is a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799317/how-can-i-get-content-of-ckeditor-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#btnPreview').on('click',function(){
  var block1 = $('#home_b1').val();
  alert(block1);
});
```

FYI: The val() method returns or sets the value attribute of the selected elements.

When used to return value: 
This method returns the value of the value attribute of the FIRST matched element.

When used to set value: 
This method sets the value of the value attribute for ALL matched elements.

Note: The val() method is mostly used with HTML form elements.

Comment: doesn't work with val()

Comment: @NicolRidente [yes it does](https://jsfiddle.net/62w7nzwn/)

Comment: i has it with .val() and it doesnt work.

Comment: i don't see any reason to not work. are you sure your jquery fires up the code block?

Comment: when i click on the button, it shows the DOM text. And i just want the text i add on the browser.

Comment: oh! got it. Are you using any 3rd party js editor(for example: tinyMCE) to write those texts? if that is the case, this text area will always return html as value.

Answer (score -1):

Try as below

```js
$(function() {
$('#btnPreview').on('click',function(){
  var block1 = $('#home_b1').val();
  alert(block1);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="form-control ckeditor" name="home_b1" id="home_b1">
  <article style="width: 55%;">
    <h2 style="text-align:center">
      <span style="color:#82b04e;font-size:24px">
        Experience the power of going prepaid
      </span>
    </h2>
    <h4 style="text-align:center">
      <span style="color:#82b04e;font-size:15px">
        Pick the plan you want with the carrier you want.
      </span>
    </h4>
    <br>
    <p style="margin-left:60px;text-align:justify;">
      <span style="font-size:20px">
        Some Text
      </span>
    </p>
  </article>
</textarea>
<button id="btnPreview">
Preview
</button>
```

Comment: When i delete all from the textarea and add some new context, this context doesn't show on the alert

Comment: No, `.text()` is as incorrect as `.html()`.

Comment: @Pointy `.html()` should return content of `<textarea>`, with `<`, `>` represented as `html` entities `&alt;`, `&gt;`. Though not clear what OP expects?

Comment: @NicolRidente, I updated the code to `.val()` , @pointy, i used .text() to get the contents with out converting as html entities as @guest271314 mentioned..

Comment: Yes, `.html()` returns the markup that's in the source, but it does *not* return the **value** of the `<textarea>` as a form element.