# CodeIgniter: I can't get the value from a textarea from html -> ajax -> php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, ckeditor

it seems I can't get the value of my textarea in php from ajax. When I try to get the value from html to javascript like so, `var content = $('textarea[name=post_content]').val(); console.log(content);`, it outputs the value of my textarea, but when I pass it to my controller using ajax, it outputs nothing.

Here is my html code:

```
<?php $attributes = array('id' => 'create_post_form'); ?>
        <?php echo form_open_multipart('', $attributes); ?>
            <label>Title:</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter Title" class="form-control" required>

            <label>Category:</label>
            <select name="category" class="form-control" required>
                <option value="">--------</option>
                <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $category['id']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></option>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </select>

            <label>Upload Image:</label>
            <input type="file" name="userfile" placeholder="Upload Image" class="form-control">

            <label>Post Content:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="15" name="post_content" placeholder="Enter Content of Post" required></textarea>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary submit-button form-control">Save</button>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

this is my ajax:

```
$('#create_post_form').submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
    data : new FormData(this),
    method : 'post',
    dataType : 'json',
    url : base_url + 'posts/create',
    async : false,
    cache : false,
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,
    success : function(data) {
        if(data['status'] == 'success')
        {
            $('#main_container').load(data['redirect_url']);
        }
        else
        {
            $('.error_container').html(data['message']);
            $('.error_container').addClass('error-border');
        }
    }
});
```

});

and this is my controller:

```
public function create()
    {
        $result['status'] = 'error';
        $result['message'] = $this->input->post('post_content');

        $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
        $this->output->set_output(json_encode($result));
        $string = $this->output->get_output();
        echo $string;
        exit();
    }
```

In my controller, I am trying to see the value of my textarea by using the error status so it would output the value as an error so i could check if I am getting the value of the textarea. But its returning no value. I am also using ckeditor. The problem started when I used the text editor.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
CKEDITOR.replace( 'post_content' );
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: sorry but we're not getting enough information from this long journey. my advise is try to log from every breakpoints first so you may know at which line you lost the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. I used [CKEditor GetData](https://docs-old.ckeditor.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#getData) to get the value of the textarea and I apppended it to formData as post_content2 like so,

```
var content = CKEDITOR.instances['post_content'].getData();
var formData = new FormData(this);
formData.append('post_content2', content);
```

I found my solution here: [how-can-i-get-content-of-ckeditor-using-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799317/how-can-i-get-content-of-ckeditor-using-jquery)

Thank you for all the replies :)

Answer (score 3):

try with `serialize()`

```
$('#create_post_form').submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
    data :  $('#create_post_form').serialize(),
    method : 'post',
    dataType : 'json',
    url : base_url + 'posts/create',
    async : false,
    cache : false,
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,
    success : function(data) {
        if(data['status'] == 'success')
        {
            $('#main_container').load(data['redirect_url']);
        }
        else
        {
            $('.error_container').html(data['message']);
            $('.error_container').addClass('error-border');
        }
    }
});
});
```

if that's doesn't work try to 1 by 1 post data

```
$('#create_post_form').submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
    data : {
      post_content : $(":input[name='post_content']").val(),
      cat : $("select[name='category']").val(),
      /* and etc post the data what u need*/

},
    method : 'post',
    dataType : 'json',
    url : base_url + 'posts/create',
    async : false,
    cache : false,
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,
    success : function(data) {
        if(data['status'] == 'success')
        {
            $('#main_container').load(data['redirect_url']);
        }
        else
        {
            $('.error_container').html(data['message']);
            $('.error_container').addClass('error-border');
        }
    }
});
```

and then in your controller try to dump all POST data like this

```
var_dump($_POST);
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove these two:

```
contentType : false,
processData : false,
```

Make you passing parameters like below:

```
var dataObj = {
      post_content : $(":input[name='post_content']").val(),
      cat : $("select[name='category']").val()
};
```

and add it like:

```
data: jQuery.param(dataObj), 
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
```

your passing parameters will be like e.g.

```
post_content=post_content&cat=catValue
```

I hope this will help